# Looking for an integral operator with eigenvalues $n+\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-equations

We have the following integral operator
$$
Ku(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s)\ u(s)\ ds,\quad u\in L^2[0,1],
$$
where
$$G(t,s)=
\begin{cases} 
s(1-t)& 0\leq s\leq t\leq 1\\ 
t(1-s)& 0\leq t\leq s\leq 1
\end{cases}$$
The eingenvalues of $K$ are
$$\lambda_n=\frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2}, \quad n=1,2,3,\ldots$$
My question is as follows. Can we find an operator, say $K'$, related to this (with a sum?) such that its eigenvalues are $n+\frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2}$?

Thank you.

Comment: You won't find an integral operator with an unbounded set of eigenvalues, since integral operators are typically bounded.

Comment: The title and text of the question don't match. In the title you refer to an integral operator with those eigenvalues, but in the text you only want an operator. Which one is it?

Comment: @joriki: you are right, I'm sorry. I edited the post

Comment: You didn't actually fix the inconsistency :-) My comment above still applies.